# kineticjs unable get the data url and Out of Memory due to file size too big.

Tags: kineticjs

Recently i help my company create a online editor photo tools. We would like to compile the final output to a huge size (H:5292 W:6000). And customer have submit 2mb images to the canvas. I have get the message of kineticjs unable get the data url. Out of Memory.

Please assist me and a brilliant thanks for paying the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible workarounds:

(Option#1) Add more memory to the computer.

(Option#2) Instead of stage.toDataURL, use stage.toImage to break the total stage into smaller images so you don't run out of memory.